# How can I find the first instance (searching up) of a value in a column?

Tags: google-sheets

Picture linked below as this is a bit tangled:

I am working with a data set that has "nested" values. There are three different types of entries: categories, then subcategories that are nested under the categories, then individual items that are nested under the subcategories (picture linked below). The entries are matched up using a filter system. Column A has the entry type, column B has the actual value, column C has the filter. The filter is always the value of entry you are nesting under. So, for a subcategory entry, Column A= "Subcategory", Column B= [name of subcategory] Column C = Column B of the category type entry above (the name of category it belongs to).

I need a way to automatically fill in the filters.

The way I am thinking I could do this is to search Column A (moving up) for the first instance of the entry type I need, and then return the value of the Column B cell in that row. Is this possible?

[image: Example Data Set Here]

Comment: there is no "baking" in A2:C12. share a copy of your sheet with example of desired output

Answer (score 0):

Given your exact data above (looking only at A14:C), delete everything from C14:C (including the header) and place the following formula in C14:

`=ArrayFormula({"FILTER"; IF((A15:A="") + (A15:A="Category"),, IF(A15:A="Subcategory", VLOOKUP(ROW(A15:A), FILTER({ROW(A15:A), B15:B}, A15:A="Category"), 2, TRUE), VLOOKUP(ROW(A15:A), FILTER({ROW(A15:A), B15:B}, A15:A="Subcategory"), 2, TRUE)))})`

This will create the title (which you can edit within the formula itself as you like) and all results for non-null rows thereafter.

You'll need to adjust the `15` in ranges to whatever the starting row of your non-header data actually is in your sheet.

Comment: Thank you internet stranger!! This worked BEAUTIFULLY and has genuinely saved me so many headaches via typos and time via manually entry. I am so grateful!!!

Comment: Happy to help, Meghan (though, wow, this was almost two months back; too bad you didn't see it earlier). Please take a moment to mark my post as "Best Answer" (the checkmark you will see next to the post). This signifies to the contributor community that the issue is fully resolved, and it helps future site visitors easily find this answer if it matches their own search. Thanks.